# Difficulty building flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, project

I have a theme for an application I'm building (EvolveSMS, to be exact). I have a base theme, and I wanted to have a way to create two different variations off of the base theme without creating two projects.

***In this case, flavor `bloo` has blue bubbles, flavor `girly` has purple bubbles.***

I was told to use **flavors**, as it would be an efficient way of handling this. I finally got the `girly` flavor to build, but it crashes when I apply the theme in the app; **I'm not asking for how to fix this crash**.

I know it has to do with a file `/res/layout/message.xml` from the `main` flavor not being shared--or, at least I think that's what the issue is. I wanted to see if maybe I had something in my `build.gradle` not configured correctly with the flavors--as I think that is the main culprit.

The `main` flavor contains all the drawable xml files needed to reference the bubbles, as well as the `layout.xml`. The `bloo` and `girly` flavors differ in their package names, their app_icon, and the bubbles being called from the drawable xml files found in the `main` flavor.

Here is a screenshot of my `build.gradle` as well as the structure of my project. Let me know if any additional information is needed.
[Screenshot of build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6aqt.png)

<s>**Edit: It would appear the issue is that *NOTHING* is being carried from the `main` flavor. The files in the `main` flavor aren't being included when I build one of the other two flavors. I already made sure I was building the correct build variant, but that doesn't seem to fix anything...**</s>

**Edit 2: I've figured it out. I've also posted my answer below.**

Comment: Your screenshot is unreadable. Please paste the `build.gradle` into your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've edited my post for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to remove certain lines from my `build.gradle` in order for my `main` flavor to build in-conjunction with either of my other flavors. Make sure the build variant is correct also.

I ended up removing:

```
main {
  res.srcDirs = ['res']
}
```

and everything built just fine. Hope I can help someone else with the same issue!